# Selected Slicer

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I'm trying to figure out a way to quickly format one or more data model-connected slicers (the number of columns, cell width/height, slicer width/height, etc), generally right after adding them to the workbook, but also on demand.  I've been trying to figure out how to traverse the `Selection` object hierarchy, but I can't seem to figure out how to go from the `Object/Rectangle` I get from the `Selection` object to the selected `Slicer` object.

I see that I can go the other way pretty easily though, as in I can access the `Shape` object directly from the `Slicer` using `ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Test1").Slicers("Test").Shape`

Is my only option to iterate all the `Slicers` in all the `SlicerCaches` until I match a `Shape` with the same name as the `Selection` (or match multiple names if I've selected more than one slicer)?

Does this make any sense? I figured this should be easier to understand, but I'm going in circles trying to research it.

Thanks for any pointers you can provide!

Edit: removed powerpivot tag because that seems irrelevant now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `Selection` at all:

```
Dim slc                   As Slicer
Set slc = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSlicer
If Not slc Is Nothing Then
    ' do stuff
End If
```

Comment: Great suggestion Rory, thanks. I had initially ruled that one out because I wanted this to work with multiple selections, which I don't think I made very clear in my post. Is there something equivalent to `ActiveSlicer` that works with multiple selected slicers at the same time?